# how to get data of current week only in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I want records from table which stores the current date when a record is inserted with in current week only.

I have tried:

```
SELECT PId 
,WorkDate 
,Hours          
,EmpId            
FROM Acb       
WHERE EmpId=@EmpId AND WorkDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: What went wrong with your query?

Comment: It is showing record from today's date to last 7 days record.@shree.pat18

Comment: Define "current week". Does it start on Sunday or Monday?

Comment: Try changing to -6 instead.

Comment: Current week starts from monday@Greenstone walker

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Define beginning of week as Monday
SELECT [...]
AND WorkDate >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
AND WorkDate <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Explanation:

- `datepart(dw, getdate())` will return the number of the day in the current week, from 1 to 7, starting with whatever you specified using [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).
- `dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate())` subtracts the necessary number of days to reach the beginning of the current week
- `CONVERT(date,getdate())` is used to remove the time portion of GETDATE(), because you want data beginning at midnight.

Comment: What might I do if I wanted to use my own date object rather the predefined getdate()?

Comment: Thank you very much.
Important to note that, `SET DATEFIRST 1` reverts back to its original state after stored procedure call.

Answer (score 11):

A better way would be

```
select datepart(ww, getdate()) as CurrentWeek
```

You can also use wk instead of ww.

[Datepart Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: I know this is old (just found via Google), but wouldn't this also return records with dates in the same week, but from different years?

Comment: duplicate answer  - answered Apr 14 '14 at 12:53 Amul Harad

Comment: @AquaAlex they are not duplicates.

Comment: keep in mind for the first week of the year for example 2019-12-31 and 2020-01-01 are in the same week but datepart(ww, getdate()) will return 53 and 1

Answer (score 2):

Its Working For Me.

```
Select * From Acb Where WorkDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
```

You have to put this line After the AND Clause `AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())`

Comment: Your retrieved data is not for the current week, you are getting data that is a week ago.

Answer (score 1):

`datepart(dw, getdate())` is the current day of the week, `dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), getdate())` should be the first day of the week, add 7 to it to get the last day of the week

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to extract current week:

```
select datepart(dw, getdate()) as CurrentWeek
```

Comment: Doesn't this return the current day of the week, rather than the current week of the year?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
    ;With CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT
    FORMAT(CreatedDate, 'MMMM-yyyy') as Months,
    CASE 
    WHEN YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min(CreatedDate)), Min(CreatedDate))) < YEAR(Min(CreatedDate))
    THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0,DATEADD(YEAR, 0 ,GETDATE())), 0) ,'MMM dd')   + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min(CreatedDate))), Min(CreatedDate))  ,'MMM dd')
    ELSE
    FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min(CreatedDate)), Min(CreatedDate)) ,'MMM dd') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min(CreatedDate))), Min(CreatedDate)) ,'MMM dd') 
    END  DateRange,
    Sum(ISNULL(Total,0)) AS Total,
    sum(cast(Duration as int)) as   Duration    
    FROM TL_VriandOPI_Vendorbilling where VendorId=@userID and CompanyId=@CompanyID
    Group By DATEPART(wk, CreatedDate) ,FORMAT(CreatedDate, 'MMMM-yyyy')
    )
    SELECT Months,DateRange,Total,Duration,
    case when DateRange=(select FORMAT(DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Min(getdate())), Min(getdate())) ,'MMM dd') + ' - ' +
    FORMAT(DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, Min(getdate()))), Min(getdate())) ,'MMM dd'))
    then 1 else 0 end as Thisweek
    FROM CTE order by Months desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DATEDIFF` works as well, however a bit hacky since it doesn't care about `datefirst`:

```
set datefirst 1; -- set monday as first day of week
declare @Now datetime = '2020-09-28 11:00';


select * 
into #Temp
from
(select 1 as Nbr, '2020-09-22 10:00' as Created
union
select 2 as Nbr, '2020-09-25 10:00' as Created
union
select 2 as Nbr, '2020-09-28 10:00' as Created) t


select * from #Temp where DATEDIFF(ww, dateadd(dd, -@@datefirst, Created), dateadd(dd, -@@datefirst, @Now)) = 0 -- returns 1 result
select * from #Temp where DATEDIFF(ww, dateadd(dd, -@@datefirst, Created), dateadd(dd, -@@datefirst, @Now)) = 1 -- returns 2 results


drop table #Temp
```