# SQL query based on date and day

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve values from my database for the past one week. Right now I am running a query to retrieve values between current time and current time - 7days. I wish to display data in a barchart for the past 1 week. So in this way, my algorithm works. But if I want to view data on a Monday, the SQL query returns values from the entire last week (since it does Today - 7 days) and so values from last week also pop up on graph. However I just want to view values from Sunday onwards. Like, if I open the app on wednesday, it should show me plot since the Sunday and not since the previous wednesday. I am looking for an SQL query which retrieves data on a weekly basis starting sunday. Or does java have a function which I can fire based on a date (every saturday for instance) to clear all data from my db, coz that way my code will work.

here's my code right now:

```
  public Cursor getStepsWeek(long time_week) throws ParseException{

    String time_past = String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy ", Locale.getDefault()).format(time_week));
    int ex = Integer.parseInt(time_past.split("-")[0]) - 7;
    String extract = String.valueOf(ex+"-") + String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(time_week));
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault()).parse(extract);

    Log.d("time past",date.getTime()+"");
    SQLiteDatabase liteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = liteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from steps_table where time_steps between " + String.valueOf(date.getTime()) + " and " + (time_week), null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051197/how-to-get-data-of-current-week-only-in-sql-server

Comment: I am aware, however my DB implementation is a bit diff, hence the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make up your mind. Do you want data "for the past one week", or do you want data for *this* week only (since Sunday).

Anyway, here is general Java code for identifying the Date of the most recent Sunday, returning today if today is Sunday.

```
// Get "now"
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// Update to most recent "first day of week",  e.g. SUNDAY in the U.S., MONDAY in France
int firstDayOfWeek = cal.getFirstDayOfWeek();
int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (dayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek)
    dayOfWeek += 7;
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, firstDayOfWeek - dayOfWeek);

// Remove time fields
int year  = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day   = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.clear();
cal.set(year, month, day);

// Get a Timestamp for use with PreparedStatement
Timestamp startDate = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

---

To get first day of year, use:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
cal.clear();
cal.set(year, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
Timestamp startDate = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: I want data beginning Sunday till Saturday for the current week.

Comment: There's a similar code for getting months I presume? Like, months since the start of the year.