# Sql query to find the names between the dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called Emp. In that there are 3 columns Name, LastWorkingDay, LeaveValue, DateofReturn. I want to write a query such that:

- The Last Working Day and DateofReturn falls between current full week

[image: Emp]

My table should return the values between '2016-10-10' and '2016-10-16' i.e current full week. So only the first 2 records should be eliminated and last 3 ones should be displayed.

```
SELECT [Name]
  ,[Last_Working_Day]
  ,[Date_of_Return]
  ,[LeaveValue]
  ,NewWeekStatus
  FROM [Emp]
  INNER JOIN [Date]
  ON [Emp].Last_Working_Day = [Date].FullDate

  WHERE [Date].NewWeekStatus = 'Current Full Week'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23060884/842112

Comment: what is `NewWeekStatus`?

Comment: Just a column in FullDate table which includes the dates for current full week ie. 10-10-16 to 16-10-16

Comment: What you mean by "Just a column in FullDate table which includes the dates for current full week ie. 10-10-16 to 16-10-16"?? What's the datatype of the column `varchar`,`datetime`,`datetime2`?? Add all the details when you ask a question.

Comment: @Shivang Add the table data and your expected output.

Comment: Hi Jibin, the logic seems to be fine but the current full week starts from 10-10-16 . My expected result is last 3 rows from screenshot. The datatype is datetime.

Comment: add more details here, Make it clear the result you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first find out first and last day of current as below.

```
 Declare @StartWeek AS datetime, @EndWeek AS datetime
 select  @StartWeek=     DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 0)
 select   @EndWeek  = DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 6)
```

Then you can use these two dates in query.

```
SELECT [Name]
  ,[Last_Working_Day]
  ,[Date_of_Return]
  ,[LeaveValue]
  ,NewWeekStatus
  FROM [Emp]
  INNER JOIN [Date]
  ON [Emp].Last_Working_Day = [Date].FullDate
  WHERE [Date].NewWeekStatus = 'Current Full Week'
  AND [Emp].Last_Working_Day BETWEEN @StartWeek  AND @EndWeek
  AND [Emp].Date_of_Return BETWEEN @StartWeek  AND @EndWeek
```

However your desire output is need to consider last week not current week.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
SELECT [Name]
  ,[Last_Working_Day]
  ,[Date_of_Return]
  ,[LeaveValue]
  ,NewWeekStatus
  FROM [Emp]
  INNER JOIN [Date]
  ON [Emp].Last_Working_Day = [Date].FullDate
  WHERE [Date].NewWeekStatus = 'Current Full Week' and (Date_of_return>='2016-10-10' and Date_of_return<='2016-10-16')
```